# Why do I get this nonsensical result for NDSolve with a delay-differential-algebraic system?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, finite-difference-method

I have the following delay-differential-algebraic system:

> \begin{align}
>  c(t) =& \kappa\min (1, \tfrac{\beta}{\alpha} a(t)), \tag{1a}\\
>  a(t) =& \left\{ \begin{array}{lcl} \frac{\alpha}{\beta} & \text{if} & s(t) > 0,\\ \min(\frac{\alpha}{\beta}, c(t-\Delta)) & \text{if} & s(t) = 0 \end{array}\right. ,\tag{1b}\\
>  \frac{\text{d} s}{\text{d} t}(t) =& c(t-\Delta) - a(t).\tag{1c}
> \end{align}

which I am trying to numerically estimate by the following code:

```
ClearAll[a, c, t, s, inic, inia]
ClearAll["Global'*"]
kappa = 2;
alpha = 1;
beta = 2;
delta = 1;
amax = 10;
T = 1.1;
inic[t_] := -t;
inia[t_] := inic[t - delta]

eq1 = c[t] == kappa*Min[1, (beta/alpha)*a[t]]
eq2 = a[t] == 
  Piecewise[{{Min[alpha/beta, c[t - delta]], s[t] == 0}, {alpha/beta, 
     s[t] > 0}}]
eq3 = s'[t] == c[t - delta] - a[t]

initialConditions = {
  a[t /; t <= 0] == inia[t],
  c[t /; t <= 0] == inic[t],
  s[t /; t <= 0] == 0}
sol = NDSolve[
  Union[{eq1, eq2, eq3}, initialConditions ], {a, c, s}, {t, -delta, 
   T}]

Plot[Evaluate[{c[t], a[t], s[t]} /. sol], {t, -delta, T}]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, but the plot does not make any sense:
[image]

I've only included a small segment after $t=1$, because all three functions completely explode to $10^{20}$ and upwards at $t=2$. This is inconsistent with the equations, which state that $c(t), a(t)$ can attain at most values of $2$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ respectively, which they attain in the plot between $t=0$ and $t=1$. Moreover the plot doesn't show the values of the functions at interval $t=[-1,0]$, even though these are given as initial conditions.

**Why does it give this strange result?**

A piece of the puzzle may be that NDSolve gives the following error:

```
NDSolve::ivcon: The given initial conditions were not consistent with the differential-algebraic equations. NDSolve will attempt to correct the values. >>
```

Comment: It appears the green line reaches `0` after `t=1`, causing a stiff system.

Answer (score 3):

I get two error messages, `NDSolve::ivcon` and `NDSolve::ndsz`, and a very strange (buggy?) set of interpolating functions.

**Re `NDSolve::ivcon`:**

Your initial conditions are inconsistent:

```
subIC =   (* turn initial conditions into substitution rules *)
 initialConditions /. {HoldPattern[Condition][p_, c_] :> 
      Inactive[Condition][Inactive[Pattern][p, Blank[]], c]} /.
        {Equal -> Rule} // Activate
(*  {a[t_ /; t <= 0] -> 1 - t, c[t_ /; t <= 0] -> -t,  s[t_ /; t <= 0] -> 0}  *)

{eq1, eq2, eq3} /. t -> 0 /. subIC
(*  {False, False, Derivative[1][s][0] == 0}  *)
```

They're inconsistent because the two sides of `eq1` and `eq2` evaluate to different numbers:

```
List @@@ {eq1, eq2, eq3} /. t -> 0 /. subIC
(*  {{0, 2}, {1, 1/2}, {Derivative[1][s][0], 0}}  *)
```

**Re `NDSolve::ndsz`:**

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you pay attention to the domain, you will see that interpolating functions have a domain of `{-1, 1}`.  Plotting outside this domain (`T = 1.1`) leads to extrapolation.

**Re strange functions:**

They do not evaluate for `t <= 0` (abnormal?):

```
{c[-0.5], a[-0.5], s[-0.5]} /. First@sol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

They evaluate between `0` and `0.9999` (normal):

```
Block[{t = {0.1, 0.5, 0.9}},
 {c[t], a[t], s[t]} /. First@sol
 ]
(*
  {{2., 2., 2.},
   {0.5, 0.5, 0.5},
   {0.045, 0.125, 0.045}}
*)
```

The extrapolation oscillates rapidly (normal, maybe?):

```
Block[{t = {1., 1.05, 1.08, 1.1}},
 {c[t], a[t], s[t]} /. First@sol
 ]
(*
  {{0., 1.18059*10^21, -4.72237*10^21, 0.},
   {0., 2.95148*10^20, -1.18059*10^21, 0.},
   {40.0292, 8.04778*10^19, 3.29637*10^20, 6.43821*10^20}}
*)
```

Replacement `t -> val` does not work and results in an invalid `InterpolatingFunction[]` (looks like a bug):

```
{c[t], a[t], s[t]} /. First@sol /. t -> 0.5
```

> Function::flpar: Parameter specification {0.5} in Function[{0.5},{1-0.5,-0.5,0}] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

*Update:*
It appears that the `` NDSolve`InitialHistory `` segment of the interpolating data has an expression that depends on the `` Global` `` variable `t`:

```
(c[t] /. First@sol /. t -> 0.5)[[0, 4, 1]]
```

> Function::flpar: Parameter specification {0.5} in Function[{0.5},{1-0.5,-0.5,0}] should be a symbol or a list of symbols.

```
(* note that the argument of  Function  has been replaced with 0.5
  {2.44141*10^-8, 
   Experimental`NumericalFunction[Function[{0.5}, {1 - 0.5, -0.5, 0}], 
    "-NumericalFunctionData-"], 2}
*)
```

It works fine if a different symbol is used:

```
c[x] /. First@sol /. x -> 0.5
(*  2.  *)
```